# django: debugging code in the view layer

Tags: django, django-views

I am developing my first django website.

I have written code in my view layer (the handlers that return an HttpResponse object to the view template (hope I am using the correct terminology).

In any case, I want to put print statements in my views.py file, so that I can debug it. However, it looks like stdout has been redirect to another stream, so I am not seeing anything printed out on my console (or even the browser).

What is the recommended way (best practice) for debugging django view layer scripts?

Comment: That's weird. `print` does work with the default Django runserver for us. (We're running Windows, if that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Python [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module. Then use the Django debug toolbar, which will catch and display all the things you send to the log.

Comment: Ah, theres a Django debug bar (cool - that should make things more familiar [to another framework I know]). How do I turn on the django debug toolbar. Could show a little snippet? the logging documentation is quite a tome for what I want to do - simply print a debug statement *SOMEWHERE*

Comment: Which Django debug toolbar? [robhudson](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) or [dcramer](http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar)? @skyeagle: The links have install instructions.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone I wasn't aware of David's fork - what does it do differently?

Comment: I don't know.  I've been meaning to use DDT, but haven't gotten around to it, so I searched on Google and found these two.  From dcramer's project page, "It includes an alternative style, performance optimizations, and some panels which may not be available in the main repository." I lack the experience with DDT at this time to make heads or tails of that.

Answer (score 3):

there are more advanced ways of doing it, but i find dropping

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

does the job.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you add the statements above to your views.py file and THEN use print as normal, or do you use another command to print what you want to display?

Comment: you add those statements where you want to break into the python debugger, from there you can inspect the state of your view function etc. It doesnt print antying by itself, but turns the terminal/window running the "python manage.py runserver" command into an interactive debugger ... screencast's etc here http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/31/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/ and more info here http://simonwillison.net/2008/May/22/debugging/

Answer (score 1):

I'd upvote dysmsyd, but I don't have the reputation.
pdb is good because it lets you step thru your procedure and follow the control flow.

If you are using the django runserver, you can print to stdout or stderr.
If you are using the mod_wsgi, you can print to stderr. 
The pprint module is also useful:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

def myview(request):
   pprint (request, sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [django-sentry](http://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry/). Especially if your project is in production stage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure django debug toolbar: `pip install django-debug-toolbar` and follow the instructions to configure it in: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar
2. `import logging`
3. Use the logging to debug: `logging.debug('My DEBUG message')`

Here is how it works on my class view:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import logging


class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug(kwargs)
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```